# "Dr Iannis had enjoyed a satisfactory day in which none of his patients had died or got any worse."

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

There is a sentence in a book "Captain Corelli's mandolin" which says:

> Dr Iannis had enjoyed a satisfactory day in which none of his patients had died or got any worse.

I tried to make a similar one.

1. "I had enjoyed a satisfactory day in which none of my tasks had been procrastinated and no time been wasted idling. "

This has been written assuming that "got any worse" is past perfect too with "had been" being used earlier with "procrastinated". Does it work like that? Otherwise, I thought it'd be correct this way:

2. "I had enjoyed a satisfactory day in which none of my tasks had been procrastinated and no time had been wasted idling."

And if "got any worse" is past simple (which I doubt), there could be another try.

3. "I had enjoyed a satisfactory day in which none of my tasks had been procrastinated and no time was wasted idling."

If "got any worse" is actually past simple, can you tell me why? The actions clearly went in the past and had ended there too so I assumed they all must go with past perfect.

I thought:

> Dr Iannis had enjoyed a satisfactory day in which none of his patients had died or got any worse.

=

> Dr Iannis had enjoyed a satisfactory day in which none of his patients had died or (had) got any worse.

Was this thinking wrong? Is the word "procrastinated" correct here? Should I use "delayed"? Or maybe there's a better saying?

Answer (score 0):

In the initial example sentence

> Dr Iannis had enjoyed a satisfactory day in which none of his patients had died or got any worse.

Neither a patient dying nor a patient getting worse would be things that Dr Iannis did. But in the proposed parallel sentence

> (1) I had enjoyed a satisfactory day in which none of my tasks had been procrastinated and no time been wasted idling.

both procrastination and idling would seem to be things that the speaker had done, or rather failed to do. This makes (1) somewhat less natural than the initial example, IMO. But it does not make (1) wrong, and if the somewhat unusual stylistic effect is intended, that is fine. But please be aware that this does have a somewhat odd effect, adn a reader is apt to read it over twice before accepting it, I think

I agree with Kate Bunting that "*procrastinate*" isn't normally used with a direct object. But I don't think that such a use is totally unacceptable, any more than verbing a noun not usually treated as a verb. It does add to the unusual effect, and might be part of the intended style. The phrase "put off" is clearer and less surprising, and would probably be better unless the odd stylistic effect is part of the author's intent, which I rather suspect it is here.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is the past perfect and *had* is intended to apply to both verbs.

Your first sentence works, except that *procrastinate* isn't normally used with a direct object. You could say 'none of my tasks had been put off'.